# Autopopulate text box based on Radio Button checked in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm just curious if there is an easy way to have my text box auto populate a string depending on whether a radio button is clicked.

For example, I have three radio buttons: residential, commercial, industrial
and I have a text box called txtCustomerType

I'm using the input from txtCustomerType to log the info to a list, but right now the user has to manually add R,C or I. The radio buttons are being used for the charge calculation (it's a little program that has different rates depending on customer)

Comment: Why not infer this info directly from the radio buttons themselves ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event handlers for this.
Under properties for the item you want, you'll find event handlers here:
[image: Event Handlers]

Then just double click the event you want, and all the necessary stuff will be automatically created for you.
And here is where you want to write the code what happens when e.g. the checked status changes:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
        textBox1.Text = "Radio button 1 checked";
}
```